# Groupby in c# to Add in new list

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have a filtered data according to date and group it according to document type and count it like:

```
Data1 - Memo
Data2 - Lett
Data3 - Memo
Data4 - Case
```

Output

```
Memo - 2
Lett - 1
Case - 1
```

I don't know if I'm doing it right. I can't display the output to View

**Model--**

```
public class ViewModelIndexTransfiles
    {
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public string idoctype { get; set; }
    public List<TransFile> transPrint { get; set; }
    public List<TransFile> summary { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller--**

```
modelPrint.transPrint = db.TransFiles.Where(s => (s.tfl_idetype == selectedtrstyp) &&
    (DbFunctions.TruncateTime(s.tfl_update) >= modelPrint.dteFrom.Date &&     
    DbFunctions.TruncateTime(s.tfl_update) <= modelPrint.dteTo.Date)).ToList();
```

**//This one is good as I was able to filter the data first according to date and display the data using modelPrint.transPrint**

```
var doccount = modelPrint.transPrint.GroupBy(o => o.tfl_idoctype).Select(x =>
    new { tfl_idoctype = x.Key, Count = x.Count() }).ToList();
```

**// this one is the grouped data. I don't know what is next to this so I can display the desired output or pass it to view.**

```
 return View(modelPrint);
```

**// I don't know which is to return :(**

**View--**

```
 @foreach (var member in Model.summary)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>Document Type</td>
        <td>Count</td>
    </tr>
     }
```

> I tried this code before the return, but It's not working.
> for (int i = 0; i < doccount.ToList().Count; i++)
> {
> modelPrint.summary.Add(
> new ViewModelIndexTransfiles
> {
> idoctype = doccount[i].tfl_idoctype,
> Count = doccount[i].Count
> });
> What am I missing?